# polar coordinates and complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Prove that $\dfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is a cube root of $1$.

I believe I must use polar coordinates to solve this.  Perhaps  $z=r\cos(\theta)+i\sin (\theta)$.  Any help would be great!

Comment: Correct @AndréNicolas .   That's  the  question.  Thanks.

Comment: You can cube as Ishfaaq suggested, or write our number as $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ for suitable $\theta$, and use the fact that the cube of this is $\cos 3\theta +i\sin 3\theta$ (special case of the de Moivre theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hint:***

$x$ is a cubic root of $y$ if and only if $x^3 = y$. So see what $x^3$ is. No need to use what you call polar coordinates.

---

**EDIT:** $$ \left({\dfrac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)^3 = \dfrac{(-1)^3 + 3(-1)^2( i\sqrt{3} ) + 3(-1)( i\sqrt{3})^2 + (i\sqrt{3})^3}{8} =  \dfrac{-1 + 3 \sqrt 3 \cdot i + 9 - 3 \sqrt 3 \cdot i }{8} = 1 $$

Comment: I tried that and I don't  think  that's the way to go.

Comment: Ooof.  I had the sqrt  over the i.  Bad idea doing  HW while sleeeeepy.  Thanks.  I see it now.  Bedtime  for the kid.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta \to z^3 = \cos (3\theta)+ i\sin (3\theta) = 1\to \cos (3\theta) = 1, \sin (3\theta) = 0$. Choose $\theta = \dfrac{2\pi}{3} \to z = -\dfrac{1}{2} + i\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Comment: Thanks!  Glad to see I was sniffing in the right direction!  Namaste.